# The Intersection of a Line and a Circle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

Suppose that we use our compass to draw a circle whose center is a point that has coordinates from a field $K$ with radius from $K$ then we get a circle  with equation $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$.  Similarly, if we use our straightedge to draw a line between two points with coordinates from $K$ we get a line with equation $ax+by+c=0$ .

Prove that, if there is a point of intersection, then its coordinates must be in a field of the form $K(\sqrt{d})$ where $d$ is some element of $K$.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: It might help if you rewrite the equation of the circle as $(x+h)^2 + (y+k)^2 = r^2$ and the equation of the line as $(y-y_1) = m * (x-x_1)$. Each constant is in $K$. Making the proper substitutions, you can in fact solve for d.

Comment: @Yunus Syed , do I have to find that x=y-y1+mx1 and substitute it into the circle equation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The intersection(s), if they exists, are solutions of the system
$$\begin {cases}
x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0\\
px+qy+n=0 \end{cases}
$$ 
(I used $p,q,m$ for the straight line to avoid confusion).

So they are the solution of a second degree equation $P^{(2)}(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ and have the form $ x= -\frac{B}{2A}\pm \frac{\sqrt{D}}{2A}$.

Comment: do I need to solve the system for x and y ? how did you find that they are the solution of a second degree equation , do you mean this solution for quadratic in general ?

Comment: I am not sure how can I use your hint to be related to its coordinates must be in a field of the form K(√D), PLEASE help me

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{K}(\sqrt{d})=\{a+b\sqrt{d}: a,b\in \mathbb{K}\}$?  See :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Examples.  The degree of the extension depends on the fact that $\sqrt{d}$ is an element of $\mathbb{K}$ or not.